# Distribution of multiplied variable into min() function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

Is distributing a variable over a $min$ call ($i \times min({1  \over i}, {1 \over j}) = min({i \over i}, {i \over j})$ correct? Intuitively it is, but I can find no difinitive answer.

PS - if anyone is curious/kind enough to read the context, I include it as a comment.

Comment: Given $x_{i,j}$, $x_{i,j} = i \times min({1 \over i}, {1 \over j})$, assume the following exist:

$$ z_j = \lim_{i \to \infty}x_{i,j},
z = \lim_{j \to \infty}z_i$$

$$ z_j = \lim_{i \to \infty}x_{i,j} = \lim_{i \to \infty} i \times min({1 \over i}, {1 \over j}) = \lim_{i \to \infty} min({i \over i}, {i \over j}) = min(\lim_{i \to \infty} {i \over i}, \lim_{i \to \infty} {i \over j}) = min(1, \infty)$$


Having gotten thus far, it's trivial to prove that  $z_j = 1, \forall j=1, 2, ...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

This is due to $i$ is non-negative.

If $b \le c$ and $a \ge 0$, then we have $ab \le ac$.

Comment: Thank you. Some days I feel like I fell into a hole between precalc and higher-level math.